# Adapting Android 10 OTA Update Code for Android 13: Need Guidance on Required Changes

Tags: android, file-io, android-permissions, android-13

I have a piece of code that downloads and installs OTA updates on Android 10 devices. However, I'm currently working on adapting it to work with Android 13, and I'm encountering issues. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
    private fun downloadFotaUpateFirmware(): String {
        val total: Long = 0

        try {
            isDownloadProgress = true //
            val url = URL(URLFILE)
            val conection = url.openConnection()
            conection.connect()
            // getting file length
            val lengthOfFile: Int = conection.getContentLength()
            Log.d(TAG, "lengthOfFile:   " + lengthOfFile)
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection Establish")
            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            val input = BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 30192)

            val output = FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ota.zip")

            val data = ByteArray(30192)

            var count: Int = 0
            var total: Float = 0f

            while ({ count = input.read(data);count }() != -1) {
                total += count

                val progress = (total * 100 / lengthOfFile).roundToInt()
                 Log.d(TAG, "Downloading Percentage   : " +progress + "%")
                output.write(data, 0, count!!)
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Download completed OTA file")
            isDownloadComplete = true
            isDownloadProgress = false


            // flushing output
            output.flush()

            // closing streams
            output.close()
            input.close()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace()

        }

        return DOWNLOADED
    }

    suspend fun fotaVerifying(): String {
        var res = ""
        val value = GlobalScope.async { // creates worker thread
            res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                otaUpdate()
            }.toString()
        }

        println(value.await()) //waits for workerthread to finish
        Log.d(TAG, "Fota MessageAfter await   :" + res)
        return res

    }

    private fun otaUpdate(): String {
        Log.d(TAG, "otaUpdate method called")

        val path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/ota.zip/"
        val updateZip = File(path)
        if (!updateZip.exists()) {
            Log.d("DownLoadFileWorkManager", "not exist")
        } else {
            Log.d("DownLoadFileWorkManager", "exist")
            try {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    delay(5)
                }
                RecoverySystem.verifyPackage(updateZip, null, null)

                Log.d("DownLoadFileWorkManager", "Successfuly verified ota package.")
                RecoverySystem.installPackage(applicationContext,updateZip)
                /*Intent().also { intent ->
                    intent.setAction("com.android.intent.otaupdate")
                    intent.putExtra("path", "/storage/emulated/0/Download/ota.zip")
                    applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent)
                }*/
//                RecoverySystem.verifyPackage(cachedFile, null, null)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //progessStatus?.setText("Verify Failed")
                Log.e("DownLoadFileWorkManager", "Corrupted package: $e")
            }
        }

        return "Verified"
    }
```

Below is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.telit.updatecheckerservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECOVERY"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

    <!--Bootlevel permission-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.telit.updatecheckerservice.MY_RUNTIME_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IPCServer">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".UpdateService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="messengerexample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've noticed that this code works perfectly on Android 10, but I'm unsure about the necessary modifications to make it compatible with Android 13.

Specifically, I need guidance on the following points:

-Compatibility Issues: Are there any known compatibility issues or changes in Android 13 that might affect this code?

-File Path Handling: The code references a file path ("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ota.zip"). Is this path still valid for Android 13, or do I need to make changes?

-File Access Permissions: With Android 13's increased focus on privacy and security, are there any additional file access permissions or changes in the permission model that I need to consider for this code to work effectively?

-Package Verification: The code uses RecoverySystem.verifyPackage and RecoverySystem.installPackage methods. Are these methods still applicable in Android 13, or should I use a different approach?

Any insights, code suggestions, or documentation references related to adapting this code for Android 13 would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for guidance on what changes are needed to ensure this code works on Android 13 devices.

Thank you for your help!

I attempted to copy the downloaded file to the /cache directory, but I encountered an error: 'Error copying ota.zip to /cache: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/ota.zip: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).'